# Looking for a 4 output brass, electronic, water valve

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm planning a small irrigation project for a home, indoor garden. I'd like to control water to four different plants using a Raspberry Pi and a single water source.

I'm looking for something like this [4 way hose faucet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Melnor-4-Way-Hose-Faucet-Connection-9009/202881087), but it needs to be electronic so that the Pi can control it (probably via a relay). I can find single solenoid valves, but haven't found anything that can handle 4 outputs.

Requirements:

- Needs to be metal, not plastic. I'd prefer brass.
- Budget: No idea. I'm going to guess less than $100, but I'm very flexible with that
- Physical size: I'd like to keep it roughly the size of the faucet I linked above
- Pressure: Needs to support normal water pressure from a hose spigot on the side of the house. Also needs to be able to support low pressure (I'm debating between having a gravity fed water basin versus just hooking up the hose. I'd like to support both applications.
- I'd like it to be normally closed, so that if I lose power, the water doesn't just start flowing everywhere.

Edit: I'm not sure what tags to put on this. Hopefully it's on topic.